# Docker IPtables chain getting removed

Tags: docker, ubuntu, iptables

The DOCKER chain in IPtables is getting flushed automatically without reboot. I have to restart the docker service in-order to re-create the chain after every time it is removed. I even saved the IPtables containing DOCKER chain to `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` and installed `iptables-persistent`, however still the IPtables gets flushed somehow and the restored one does not contain the DOCKER chain. Any idea as to what is the reason behind the same. This is happening on an Ubuntu box.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like there won't be an answer any time soon: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12294

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this may not be on the Docker side. I had a similar situation and finally found that a previous sysadmin had set cron to reload iptables config every minute